# Newly installed patio door with gap between fixed and sliding doors

Tags: insulation, sliding-glass-door

Last week I had a patio door installed and everything looked right to me. However, I noticed that there was a gap between the fixed and sliding doors. I'm not a contractor so I did not think much of it at the time. However in the last couple of days we have had a considerable drop in temperature and our house is now freezing inside. This led me to notice that there is a considerable gap between the doors, which seems to be entirely due to them being offset. On top of that there is a considerable amount of noise that is coming in from the outside that I had not noticed initially. This is because I live in a constantly noisy house and wouldn't have noticed this issue to begin with. Is this an issue that can be remedied with the existing doors or have I been screwed by my contractor? I ask because he's the second guy I had come out for this issue. The first I fired because his guys were screwing around and not addressing the core issue.

I appreciate further insight into remediation of this because winter is only going to get colder.

I have followed up with my contractor but am waiting for his response. I am hoping to have some competent insight into what could be done so I can avoid having the wool pulled over my eyes, should that occur.

[image: sliding glass doors overlapping and not sealed]

[image: closeup between doors showing finger-width gap]

Comment: Looks like the door is too big for the frame. When closed the frames should overlap and seal that gap. Can you post a picture of the entire door, with the operable side shut.

Comment: That's incredibly frustrating. I was told that this was the correct size. Am I just screwed now?

Comment: I cannot believe that any competent tradesman would install the door and leave it that way.  If the 2 sides do not overlap it is the wrong size and should not have been installed.  A measuring tape would have discovered this at the inception.

Comment: Frame too small, or panels too big.  If it's a standard door, it may be possible to get a smaller panel(s).

Comment: I’ll give you a bit of hope: this looks like a screwup at the manufacturer level, and should be easy to remedy. (Doors and frames get shipped as one unit.) Now, as to why they left it like that… well, that’s a whole different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the pictures it appears the door is too large for the frame.

When closed, the frames should overlap and seal that gap.

The only time you should be able to get your fingers in there like that is when the door is open.

For the time being, you could hang a curtain or even try some caulking backer rod to seal the gap if you don't use the door that often.

Comment: He's going to be coming out later today to take a look at the issue. Unfortunately he seemed like the competent contractor and surely charged me like it. Do you have any words of advice that can empower me to be able to competently respond to the issue when he's here?

Comment: Stay calm, tell him you have done some research and it appears the door is the incorrect size and that it should be fixed. You can't properly heat your home with air gaps like that.  If he doesn't offer to fix it, I would reach out to a reputable contractor, hopefully someone with recommendations from friends/family and ask for a quote to fix it and then you might have to take the guy to small claims court. If he has an online presence, leave a negative review if he fails to fix it.

Comment: I appreciate it. He was recommended by a friend, so I have a tinge of hope that he will fix the issue. He's actually been transparent about how he's fixed issues in the past when his guys have done things incorrectly. Fortunately I have the remainder of the day to calm down before he arrives.

Comment: @mr_ohdee How'd it go?

Comment: I appreciate you following up. 

It turns out that it was a whole jumbled issue. After I emailed my contractor he got back to me almost immediately and let me know that he was going to send back out the guy to take a look. 

Apparently one of the panels was incorrectly labeled by the manufacturer. They had the correct size installed just after lunch on Monday.